# VS Code: Include External OpenCV Install with CMake Tools

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am trying to set up an OpenCV C++ project using VS Code. I am able to compile the project just fine from the command line, by manually generating CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.17")
project(simple-demo)

# set OpenCV_DIR variable equal to the path to the cmake install
set(OpenCV_DIR /Users/tstoff/git/opencv/install/lib/cmake/opencv4)

# Tell compiler to use C++ 14 features
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# configure the necessary common CMake environment variables
# needed to include and link the OpenCV program into this
# demo project, namely OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS and OpenCV_LIBS
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# tell the build to include the headers from OpenCV
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# specify the executable target to be built
add_executable(simple-demo main.cpp)

# tell it to link the executable target against OpenCV
target_link_libraries(simple-demo ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

which I can build using `make` and `cmake ..` from a build directory. But I want to use the power of the VS Code [CMake Tools](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/) library! How do I add external libraries to VS Code projects, preferably using CMake Tools? Many thanks!